# how toggle div class when click on < p >

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

I have this code:

```
<p class="faqsli" onclick="faqs1.className='faqsanswer';">
  چگونه ایمیل دهی سایت را محدود کنم؟
</p>
```

`<div id="faqs1" class="faqshide">sometext</div>`
my css's !

```
.faqsli{
padding: 0px 16px 0px 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(miniic_li.png);
background-position: right 5px;
}
.faqshide{
display:none;
}
.faqsanswer{
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
margin-right:25px;
}
```

It works perfect.

When someone clicks `<p>` the `<div>` class changes and shows to the user, but I'd also like the `<div>` to hide when the `<p>` is clicked for the second time.  What must I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<p class="faqsli" onclick="document.getElementById('faqs1').className='faqsanswer';">
```

Simply referring to the ID of the div does not get a reference to that div. You can use `document.getElementById()` to reference the `div` and then set the `className`.

If you're using jQuery this might make more sense:

**UPDATE: For dynamic `div` and `p`**

HTML

```
<p class="faqsli" data-div="faqs1">
    <!-- text here -->
</p>

<div id="faqs1" class="faqshide">
    <!-- other text here -->
</div>
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

    $( document ).on( 'click', '.faqsli', function () {

        var id = $( this ).attr( 'data-div' );
        $( '#' + id ).toggle();

    } );

} );
```

Comment: its not html actully i get these from sql with while($f = mysql_fetch_array)){ echo  <br><p class=\"faqsli\" onClick=\"faqs$faqsid.className='faqsanswer';\" >".
  $ffaqs['question'].
  "</p><br><div class=\"faqshide\" id=\"faqs$faqsid\">".$ffaqs['answer'].'</div>

Comment: hmmm i cant use doument ready and js file because user can add any question  with any div id='someting'

Comment: @masiharastooyi I have updated my answer to account for dynamic elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use `toggleClass` on click event.

```
<p class="faqsli" onclick="$('#faqs1').toggleClass('faqsanswer faqshide');">
  چگونه ایمیل دهی سایت را محدود کنم؟
</p>
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/h6tWy/)

Comment: this? i want change div class when click on p  and its not html actully i get these from sql with while($f = mysql_fetch_array)){ echo  <br><p class=\"faqsli\" onClick=\"faqs$faqsid.className='faqsanswer';\" >".
  $ffaqs['question'].
  "</p><br><div class=\"faqshide\" id=\"faqs$faqsid\">".$ffaqs['answer'].'</div>

Comment: @masiharastooyi So change the selector. Updated.

Comment: <p class="faqsli" onclick="$('#faqs1').toggleClass('faqsanswer');">چگونه ایمیل دهی سایت را محدود کنم؟</p> not work

Comment: @masiharastooyi Take a look my update, I added a working demo to it.